# ./configure: Permission denied while trying to install python on chromebook

Tags: linux, chromebook

I just bought a chromebook 2 and I already put the laptop on development mode.

I did the `alt + ctrl + t` and the I typed shell.

When I try to install python with the `sudo ./configure` command, I get `Permission denied`.

I also did `chmod +x`, but still no luck.

I appreciate if any help

Comment: Doesn't python come pre-installed?

Comment: It doesn't come with python installed.

Comment: use a package manager .

Comment: Never run configure as root.  The only thing you need to do as root is the final install.  Try `./configure && make && sudo make install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend Installing Chromebrew : http://skycocker.github.io/chromebrew/
It is a package manager for ChromeOS. After installing that just type in ,

```
crew install python
```

**Alternate Methods :**

Python Shell
You can install this plugin, Python Shell into Chrome. 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/python-shell/gdiimmpmdoofmahingpgabiikimjgcia?hl=en

Skulpt Interpreter
Lastly you can check out the Skulpt Interpreter.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/skulpt-interpreter/bocjplmmdjglmffmpofmmndklbdpcmeb?hl=en&gl=US

Comment: When I installed Chromebrew, it installed python for me. I guess it come in the package. Thanks